# Creating clusters based on a plot

Tags: r

I have a  dataset like this:

| Region | Year | Month | rate | residuals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | 1 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 2010 | 1 | 4.0 | 0.5 |

This dataset continues it has 15'000 observations.

I created a scatter plot :

```
plot(df$full.residuals, df$rate, main="Scatterplot", 
   xlab="rate", ylab="Residuals")
```

Now I can't do it further to create cluster in the plot? Does anyone know how to create clusters in the plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I created some more random datapoints, because with 2 points it will be hard to create clusters. You could use [kmeans](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/kmeans) as an algorithm to create clusters. In this case I decide to create 2 clusters which you can change if you want. With the `factoextra` package you can create some nice visualizations like this:

```r
library(factoextra)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(rate = runif(20, 0, 1),
                 full.residuals = runif(20, 0, 1))

kmeans_cluster <- kmeans(scale(df), 2, nstart = 5)

kmeans_cluster$cluster
#>  [1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2

fviz_cluster(kmeans_cluster, data = df,
             palette = c("#2E9FDF", "#00AFBB"), 
             geom = "point",
             ellipse.type = "convex", 
             ggtheme = theme_bw())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I would suggest to have a look at this [link](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/k-means-clustering-visualization-in-r-step-by-step-guide/) for some extra information about using this package.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Is it possible that sometimes some points don't belong to a cluster?

Comment: I mean, do all points always have a cluster family or are some points sometimes alone?

Comment: @JaimeGilmartin, Np! in this case they always have a cluster family.